# How do I sample arbitrary probability mass functions? (Archimedean Copula)

Tags: sampling, random-generation, copula

I'm trying to use an algorithm (Marshall, Olkin) for exchangable archimedean Copula to generate realizations of multivariate probability distributions.

[image: Algorythm]

One step includes sampling V which is F distributed where F is the inverse Laplace-Stieltjes transform of the respective generator.

Concernig the families Clayton and Gumbel I can simply implement rgamma(.) and rstable(.) for F into the algorythm to generate a V, but for Frank, Joe, and Ali-Mikhail-Haq I dont have common distributions but arbitrary (discrete) probability mass functions.

[image: probability mass functions]

How could I sample those for a V?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if you already found an answer to your question. Anyway it could be useful to somebody else.

The sampling of $V$ is usually obtained through numerical inversion of the Laplace transform of the generator. There are many algorithms available to solve this problem, you could give a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358524/sampling-from-characteristic-moment-generating-function/381407#381407) for example.

The Marshall & Olkin method you mention in your question is treated in sec 4.4 of the following [paper](https://www.kent.ac.uk/smsas/personal/msr/webfiles/rlaptrans/SimRandom4.pdf) by prof. Ridout (ref. Generating random numbers from a distribution specified by its Laplace transform). The author of the paper I mentioned above published also some Rcode on his personal webpage (I think it could be helpful to give a look at them).

Hope this helps.